# Function that always keep returning new data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm kind of a new to python and i'm trying to run a code for a program, but i'm stuck in this part where i need a Function that always keep returning new data, here's a part of the code that always keep returning a zeros!

```
import time

def forloop():
  for i in range(0,10000):
    return i

while True:
  time.sleep(0.25)
  print(forloop())
```

Comment: Did you want to produce the numbers 0 through to 9999 (and then start at 0 again perhaps) or did you want to count on ad infinitum?

Comment: I've added a (better) option to re-start counting from 0 each time too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `forloop()` and do `return i` inside it, it returns from the function, and the next time you call `forloop()` it will start from the beginning. What you want to use are generator functions

You can use `generator functions` for this (using `yield` statement) to yield the values instead of `return` .

Example -

```
def forloop():
  for i in range(0,10000):
    yield i

x = forloop()
while True:
   try :
       time.sleep(0.25)
       print(next(x))
   except StopIteration:
       x = forloop()
```

`next(x)` throws `StopIteration` exception if the generator has been exhausted, in which case we catch that exception and recreate the generator.

Comment: Why not just have the generator restart the count each time?

Comment: There are a million ways to go about this, I just used 1 that came to mind.

Comment: Also, the code posted by the OP looks like a MCVE , just to explain his usecase , his actual scenario maybe much more complex, in which case knowing about `StopIteration` might be handy.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If you are looking at that then even the generator function is not necessary, `function` as such is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns immediately, and each time you call it you start at `0` again.

You can do what you want with a regular function; use a global and keep incrementing that:

```
_counter = -1
def increasing():
    global _counter
    _counter += 1
    return counter
```

but a *better* idea would be to use a [*generator function*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators):

```
def increasing():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        yield counter
        counter += 1
```

and you can use that in a loop:

```
for count in increasing():
    print(count)
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

The standard library already includes such a generator: the [`itertools.count()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) does just that. Together with the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) you can pretty much recreate your `while` loop:

```
from itertools import count

counter = count()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print(next(counter))
```

If you wanted to continually loop over the the values 0 through to 9999, then you'd write a custom generator function that does just that:

```
def count_to_9999_and_restart():
    while True:
        for i in range(10000):
            yield i
```

and you can use *that* generator:

```
counter = count_to_9999_and_restart()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print(next(counter))
```

Comment: This would not loop from 0-9999 it would just keep incrementing indefinitely

Comment: I assumed it was because they wanted to start with *something*. The question asks for something that *always keeps returning data*.

Comment: Well based on the accepted answer they must want to continually restart, they must also like typing unnecessary lines of code.

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised at the choice of accepted answer. Not that I voted on anything posted here myself so far.

Answer (score -2):

Try using a global variable to keep track of where the function reached inbetween calls:

```
counter = 0
def forloop():
  global counter
  counter += 1
  return counter
```